# Need help understand the order of execution from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, computer-science, masm

Memory map with execution time:
[image: Memory Map with execution time.]

And this is the assembly code that corresponds to it:

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27027.1 

    TITLE   c:\LearningTree\348LM\CoursePrograms\348L\Chap1\var.c
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB LIBCMT
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  _x
_DATA   SEGMENT
COMM    _ret:BYTE
_DATA   ENDS
_DATA   SEGMENT
_x  DD  064H
_DATA   ENDS
PUBLIC  _main
PUBLIC  _test
_BSS    SEGMENT
_si DD  01H DUP (?)
?i@?1??main@@9@9 DD 01H DUP (?)             ; `main'::`2'::i
_BSS    ENDS
_DATA   SEGMENT
_sj DD  017H
?y@?1??main@@9@9 DW 063H                ; `main'::`2'::y
_DATA   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
; File c:\learningtree\348lm\courseprograms\348l\chap1\var.c
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_i1$ = -8                       ; size = 4
_c2$ = -2                       ; size = 1
_c1$ = -1                       ; size = 1
_ui$ = 8                        ; size = 4
_i$ = 12                        ; size = 4
_s$ = 16                        ; size = 2
_us$ = 20                       ; size = 2
_c$ = 24                        ; size = 1
_uc$ = 28                       ; size = 1
_l$ = 32                        ; size = 4
_ul$ = 36                       ; size = 4
_x$ = 40                        ; size = 4
_y$ = 44                        ; size = 2
_test   PROC

; 59   : {

  00000 55       push    ebp
  00001 8b ec        mov     ebp, esp
  00003 83 ec 08     sub     esp, 8

; 60   :    char c1;
; 61   :    int i1;
; 62   :    char c2;
; 63   : 
; 64   :    ui = 1;

  00006 c7 45 08 01 00
    00 00        mov     DWORD PTR _ui$[ebp], 1

; 65   :    i = 2;

  0000d c7 45 0c 02 00
    00 00        mov     DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], 2

; 66   :    s = 3;

  00014 b8 03 00 00 00   mov     eax, 3
  00019 66 89 45 10  mov     WORD PTR _s$[ebp], ax

; 67   :    us = 4;

  0001d b9 04 00 00 00   mov     ecx, 4
  00022 66 89 4d 14  mov     WORD PTR _us$[ebp], cx

; 68   :    c = 5;

  00026 c6 45 18 05  mov     BYTE PTR _c$[ebp], 5

; 69   :    uc = 6;

  0002a c6 45 1c 06  mov     BYTE PTR _uc$[ebp], 6

; 70   :    l = 7;

  0002e c7 45 20 07 00
    00 00        mov     DWORD PTR _l$[ebp], 7

; 71   :    ul = 8;

  00035 c7 45 24 08 00
    00 00        mov     DWORD PTR _ul$[ebp], 8

; 72   :    x = 9;

  0003c c7 45 28 09 00
    00 00        mov     DWORD PTR _x$[ebp], 9

; 73   :    y = 10;

  00043 ba 0a 00 00 00   mov     edx, 10            ; 0000000aH
  00048 66 89 55 2c  mov     WORD PTR _y$[ebp], dx

; 74   :    c1 = 11;

  0004c c6 45 ff 0b  mov     BYTE PTR _c1$[ebp], 11 ; 0000000bH

; 75   :    c2 = 12;

  00050 c6 45 fe 0c  mov     BYTE PTR _c2$[ebp], 12 ; 0000000cH

; 76   :    i1 = 13;

  00054 c7 45 f8 0d 00
    00 00        mov     DWORD PTR _i1$[ebp], 13    ; 0000000dH

; 77   :    return ui * 2 + l;

  0005b 8b 45 08     mov     eax, DWORD PTR _ui$[ebp]
  0005e 8b 4d 20     mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _l$[ebp]
  00061 8d 04 41     lea     eax, DWORD PTR [ecx+eax*2]

; 78   : }

  00064 8b e5        mov     esp, ebp
  00066 5d       pop     ebp
  00067 c3       ret     0
_test   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
; File c:\learningtree\348lm\courseprograms\348l\chap1\var.c
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_l$ = -24                       ; size = 4
_ui$ = -20                      ; size = 4
_ul$ = -16                      ; size = 4
_s$ = -12                       ; size = 2
_us$ = -8                       ; size = 2
_uc$ = -2                       ; size = 1
_c$ = -1                        ; size = 1
_argc$ = 8                      ; size = 4
_argv$ = 12                     ; size = 4
_envp$ = 16                     ; size = 4
_main   PROC

; 28   : {

  00000 55       push    ebp
  00001 8b ec        mov     ebp, esp
  00003 83 ec 18     sub     esp, 24            ; 00000018H

; 29   :    unsigned char uc;
; 30   :    static short y = 99;
; 31   :    short s;
; 32   :    char c;
; 33   :    unsigned short us;
; 34   :    static int i;
; 35   :    unsigned int ui;
; 36   :    long l;
; 37   :    unsigned long ul;
; 38   : 
; 39   :    if (i < 4) {

  00006 83 3d 00 00 00
    00 04        cmp     DWORD PTR ?i@?1??main@@9@9, 4
  0000d 7d 15        jge     SHORT $LN4@main

; 40   :        ui = us + s - c;

  0000f 0f b7 45 f8  movzx   eax, WORD PTR _us$[ebp]
  00013 0f bf 4d f4  movsx   ecx, WORD PTR _s$[ebp]
  00017 03 c1        add     eax, ecx
  00019 0f be 55 ff  movsx   edx, BYTE PTR _c$[ebp]
  0001d 2b c2        sub     eax, edx
  0001f 89 45 ec     mov     DWORD PTR _ui$[ebp], eax

; 41   :    }

  00022 eb 12        jmp     SHORT $LN2@main
$LN4@main:

; 42   :    else {
; 43   :        ul = si - sj * 2;

  00024 a1 00 00 00 00   mov     eax, DWORD PTR _sj
  00029 d1 e0        shl     eax, 1
  0002b 8b 0d 00 00 00
    00       mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _si
  00031 2b c8        sub     ecx, eax
  00033 89 4d f0     mov     DWORD PTR _ul$[ebp], ecx
$LN2@main:

; 44   :    }
; 45   : 
; 46   :    while (sj > c) {

  00036 0f be 55 ff  movsx   edx, BYTE PTR _c$[ebp]
  0003a 39 15 00 00 00
    00       cmp     DWORD PTR _sj, edx
  00040 7e 1e        jle     SHORT $LN3@main

; 47   :        uc = y - 3;

  00042 0f bf 05 00 00
    00 00        movsx   eax, WORD PTR ?y@?1??main@@9@9
  00049 83 e8 03     sub     eax, 3
  0004c 88 45 fe     mov     BYTE PTR _uc$[ebp], al

; 48   :        sj++;

  0004f 8b 0d 00 00 00
    00       mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _sj
  00055 83 c1 01     add     ecx, 1
  00058 89 0d 00 00 00
    00       mov     DWORD PTR _sj, ecx

; 49   :    }

  0005e eb d6        jmp     SHORT $LN2@main
$LN3@main:

; 50   : 
; 51   :    ret = test(ui, i, s, us, c, uc, l, ul, x,  y);

  00060 0f bf 15 00 00
    00 00        movsx   edx, WORD PTR ?y@?1??main@@9@9
  00067 52       push    edx
  00068 a1 00 00 00 00   mov     eax, DWORD PTR _x
  0006d 50       push    eax
  0006e 8b 4d f0     mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _ul$[ebp]
  00071 51       push    ecx
  00072 8b 55 e8     mov     edx, DWORD PTR _l$[ebp]
  00075 52       push    edx
  00076 0f b6 45 fe  movzx   eax, BYTE PTR _uc$[ebp]
  0007a 50       push    eax
  0007b 0f be 4d ff  movsx   ecx, BYTE PTR _c$[ebp]
  0007f 51       push    ecx
  00080 0f b7 55 f8  movzx   edx, WORD PTR _us$[ebp]
  00084 52       push    edx
  00085 0f bf 45 f4  movsx   eax, WORD PTR _s$[ebp]
  00089 50       push    eax
  0008a 8b 0d 00 00 00
    00       mov     ecx, DWORD PTR ?i@?1??main@@9@9
  00090 51       push    ecx
  00091 8b 55 ec     mov     edx, DWORD PTR _ui$[ebp]
  00094 52       push    edx
  00095 e8 00 00 00 00   call    _test
  0009a 83 c4 28     add     esp, 40            ; 00000028H
  0009d a2 00 00 00 00   mov     BYTE PTR _ret, al

; 52   : 
; 53   :    return 0;

  000a2 33 c0        xor     eax, eax

; 54   : }

  000a4 8b e5        mov     esp, ebp
  000a6 5d       pop     ebp
  000a7 c3       ret     0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

I understand the allocation of the variables, and how to determine if they belong in data, bss, or text. But I cannot understand how to tell when a frame starts or stops, the order, etc.

I'm lost on:

1. The order in the assembly code
2. How to know when a frame begins and ends.

Comment: I'm also unsure on the frame pointers, why is mains frame pointer in tests stack after c1 and c2?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking -- the 'frame pointer' is a register, and "main's fram pointer" is the contents during main.  During test, the frame pointer has the value of tests frame poniter, which is below main's frame on the stack.  So the first thing that test does is saves the contents of fp (with main's value) and sets it to its own value.  Then before it returns, it restores main's frame pointer.

Comment: If you look at the image, in test's frame, it shows i1, c1, then c2, and then main's fp, and return to main. Why is main's fp and return to main after i1, c1, and c2?

Comment: Because stack grows downwards. `call` put the return address on the stack, then main's fp was saved by the `push ebp` then `c1` and `c2` were allocated by `sub esp, 8`

Comment: Thank you, that cleared some things up for me.

Comment: Could you help explain the 000000 and ssssss besides y, uc,c, etc in the memory map?

Comment: THe 000000's just mean that when the value was store on the stack ithe upper bits were set to 0 (`zero extended`). `ssssss` just means the value was `sign extended` when placed on the stack `s` = sign